# HTML email horizontally extends fixed width in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, width

I've got a lot of time wrapped up in this template, it's mobile optimized and is compatible with dotMailer's easybuilder software for noobs to edit.

When the email is received by Outlook (dektop client) it extends the right width horizontally with some elements following suit. Elements that are full width do not extend (not that I want them to extend!)

I'd really appreciate your help guys - please find the screenshots attached and the code snippet below (due to character limits here I'll only paste in the header/upper content).

[SCREENSHOTS](http://smg.photobucket.com/user/pageheaven/library/Email%20Template%20Issues)

```
<style>.ReadMsgBody{width:100%}.ExternalClass{width:100%}#outlook a{padding:0}body{width:100%!important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0;padding:0}a img{border:0}a,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{color:inherit!important}img{outline:0;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}.applelinks a{color:#333;text-decoration:none}.ExternalClass{width:100%!important}.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div{line-height:100%}.ExternalClass img[class^=Emoji]{width:10px!important;height:10px!important;display:inline!important}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio :1.5),only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio :1.5),only screen and (max-device-width:480px){table[class~=hide],td[class~=hide],img[class~=hide],font[class~=hide]{display:none!important}td[class~=grey_border]{padding:5px!important;margin:0!important}td[class~=eem_frame]{padding:10px!important}table[class~=ee_element],table[class~=eeb_width],table[class~=eev_element]{width:100%!important}table[class~=eem_outerzone],td[class~=eem_outerzone]{max-width:640px!important;min-width:310px!important;width:100%!important}td[class~=ved-scaled-cols],table[class="ee_columns"]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:100%!important;margin:0!important;padding:10px!important}td[class~=ved-scaled-cols-screenshots],table[class="ee_columns_screenshots"]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:90%!important;padding:15px!important;margin-left:auto!important;margin-right:auto!important;align:center!important}td[class~=ved-scaled-cols-newsimages],table[class="ee_columns_newsimages"]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:90%!important;padding:15px!important;margin-left:auto!important;margin-right:auto!important;align:center!important}td[class~=ved-scaled-cols-button1],table[class="ee_columns_b1"]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:200px!important;padding-top:15px!important;padding-bottom:15px!important}td[class~=ved-scaled-cols-button2],table[class="ee_columns_button2"]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:100%!important;max-height:54px!important;padding:10px 20px 10px 0!important}img[class~=ee_editable]{height:auto!important;max-width:640px!important;width:100%!important}.ee_editable{width:100%!important;height:auto!important}.ee_columns>tbody>tr>td:not(.ee_dropzone),.ee_columns>tr>td:not(.ee_dropzone),.ee_columnstd:not(.ee_dropzone){display:inherit!important}.ee_columns_screenshots>tbody>tr>td:not(.ee_dropzone),.ee_columns_screenshots>tr>td:not(.ee_dropzone),.ee_columns_screenshotstd:not(.ee_dropzone){display:inherit!important}.ee_columns_newsimages>tbody>tr>td:not(.ee_dropzone),.ee_columns_newsimages>tr>td:not(.ee_dropzone),.ee_columns_newsimagestd:not(.ee_dropzone){display:inherit!important}table[class~="eem_stack320"],td[class~="eem_stack320"]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;min-width:320px!important;width:100%!important;margin:0!important;padding:0!important;alignment-adjust:central!important}.eem_stack{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:100%!important;margin:0!important;padding:0!important}td[class~=eem_stack]{display:block!important;clear:both!important;width:100%!important;margin:0!important;padding:0}div[class~=center],div[class~=center] *{text-align:center!important;line-height:22px!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;font-size:18px!important}div[class~=left],div[class~=left] *{text-align:left!important;line-height:22px!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;font-size:18px!important}div[class~=right],div[class~=right] *{text-align:left!important;line-height:22px!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;font-size:18px!important}td[class~=eem_smallimage]{line-height:normal!important;height:auto!important}font[class~=title-text],table[class="title-text"]{line-height:22px!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;font-size:20px!important}font[class~=main-text],table[class="main-text"]{line-height:20px!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;font-size:18px!important}font[class~=section-title-text],table[class="section-title-text"]{line-height:26px!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;font-size:24px!important}font[class~=unsubscribe-text],table[class="unsubscribe-text"]{line-height:30px!important;padding-bottom:20px!important;font-size:24px!important}};.ee_editable{width:100%!important;height:auto!important}</style><style type="text/css">table{border-collapse:collapse}</style><table style="table-layout:auto"class="ee_mobiletemplate"bgcolor="#ffffff"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%"><tbody><tr><td><table class="eem_outerzone"style="border:1px solid rgb(153,153,153);table-layout:auto;"align="center"bgcolor="#e1e1e1"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="680"><tbody><tr><td class="grey_border"style="padding:18px;"><table style="width:640px;table-layout:auto"class="eem_outerzone" bgcolor="#e1e1e1"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="640"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:0px"class="ee_dropzone"width="640"><table style="width:640px;table-layout:auto"class="hide"bgcolor="#e1e1e1"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="640"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:5px"><table style="table-layout:auto"class="ee_customedit ee_sociallinks"data-title="Social sharing"data-edit="social"border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"width="230"><tbody><tr><td class="ee_socialcontent"><div class="eesocial"><table style="table-layout:auto"border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=4"><img title="Facebook"style="width:24px; height:24px;"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/facebook.png" border="0"height="24"width="24"></a></td><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=36"><img title="GooglePlus"style="width:24px; height:24px;"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/googleplus.png" border="0"height="24"width="24"></a></td><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=12"><img title="LinkedIn"style="width:24px; height:24px;"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/linkedin2.png"border="0"height="24"width="24"></a></td><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=32"><img title="Twitter" style="width:24px;height:24px"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/twitter.png"border="0"height="24"width="24"></a></td><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=1"><img title="Delicious"style="width:24px;height:24px;"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/delicious.png"border="0"height="24"width="24"></a></td><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=3"><img title="reddit"style="width:24px;height:24px;"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/reddit.png"border="0" height="24"width="24"></a></td><td style="text-align:left;padding-right:5px"><a href="http://$SOCIALBOOKMARK$?b=5"><img title="StumbleUpon"style="width:24px;height:24px;"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/sys/socnet/stumbleupon.png"border="0"height="24"width="24"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="width:640px;table-layout:auto"class="eem_outerzone"bgcolor="#e1e1e1"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="640"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;border-left:1px solid #999;border-top:1px solid #999;border-bottom:1px solid #999;border-right:1px solid #999"class="ee_dropzone"width="640"><table style="width:640px;table-layout:auto"class="ee_element"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="hide"style="padding:0;width:210px"bgcolor="#000000"width="35%"><table class="ee_element"style="width:208px;table-layout:auto"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="208"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px"><img src="https://my.dotmailer.com/resources/handlers/dcimage.ashx?text=Sys - header logo - Corporate&amp;id=13743"></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td style="width:390px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px"bgcolor="#000000"><div style="padding-top:8px;text-align:right"class="ee_editable center"><font style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;color:#f3fff1;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">July 2013</font></div><div style="text-align:right"class="ee_editable hide"><img style="width:369px;height:56px"class="vedpw390"src="https://my.dotmailer.com/resources/handlers/dcimage.ashx?text=Sys - header forward and view in browser&amp;id=13746"border="0"width="369"height="56"></div></td></tr></tbody></table><table class="ee_element" style="width:640px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640"><tbody><tr><td class="eem_smallimage" style="padding:0;width:640px;line-height:6px" height="6"><img src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/2011/44869/2977177_greendivider640.png" class="ee_editable vedpw640 ee_pnggif_image" style="display:block;width:640px;height:6px" border="0" width="640" height="6"></td></tr></tbody></table><table class="ee_element" style="width:640px;table-layout:auto;background-color:#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:0px;width:640px"><a href="#"target="_blank"><img src="/img.ashx?__i__=https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/9/6/8/4/4/files/3578369_main_feature_graphic_640xany.png" alt="Main Feature Graphic"width="640"class="ee_editable vedpw640"style="display:block;width:640px;"align="middle"border="0"></a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="width:640px;table-layout:auto"class="ee_element"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:0;width:640px"><table class="ee_element"style="width:640px;table-layout:auto"bgcolor="#ffffff"border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:0;width:20px"rowspan="2"width="20"><img src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/2011/44869/2876533_spacer.gif"style="display:block"height="10"width="20"></td><td style="padding:0;width:600px"width="100%"><div style="text-align:left" class="ee_editable"><font class="title-text" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;color:#76b900;font-size:15px;line-height:18px;font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase"><a href="#"target="_blank"style="text-decoration:none;color:#76b900"><br>MAIN FEATURE</a></font></div><div style="text-align:left"class="ee_editable"><font class="main-text"style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-size:12px;color:#000;line-height:14px;font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Integer iaculis dapibus scelerisque. Quisque diam ligula, pulvinar at quam eget, volutpat adipiscing nulla. Ut et massa tempor, pharetra diam ac, eleifend quam. In rhoncus rhoncus elit a auctor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque blandit nisl eget pretium sagittis. Praesent euismod urna ut commodo mollis. Phasellus lacinia orci at posuere bibendum. Curabitur imperdiet odio nunc, tempus consequat mauris fermentum a.<br/><br/>Morbi ac tellus felis. In libero orci, eleifend dictum tempus consequat, pellentesque nec nisi. Etiam vitae nisl tincidunt, dictum nisi in, condimentum nulla. Morbi euismod vestibulum urna sit amet venenatis.</font></div></td><td style="padding:0;width:20px"rowspan="2"width="20"><img src="https://my.dotmailer.com/cmpimg/2011/44869/2876533_spacer.gif"style="display:block"height="10"width="20"></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px"class="ee_dropzone"bgcolor="#ffffff"width="100%"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first nested table you are using a combination of percentage and pixel widths and declaring in both html and css. Just use `width=""`, not the css width. You also don't need any `<tbody>` tags.

This should get you started:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">           
    /* Client-specific Styles */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: default; color: #000001 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#F9F9F9" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="540" height="60" valign="bottom">
nest your top table here.
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="540" height="60" bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #FFFFFF;">
nest table in here if needed
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="540" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="" width="540" height="400" alt="Main Graphic">
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="540" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="30">&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td width="480" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
            &nbsp;<br>
            <font style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #3c8a2e;">HEADER</font>
            <br><br>
            text at bottom
            <br>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td width="30">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="540" height="30">
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: This helped me locate the issue, thank you. There were quite a few additional issues that cropped up whilst investigating the initial issue.

Cheers and kindly appreciated!